# scss nesting , repeat necessary

Tags: css, sass

one quick question :

why do i have to repeat the first aruments like position and top for every nested state ? i thought the point is not to repeat it?
If i remove the states in the nested classes, it doesnt work.

I wanted to use them like:

logo has to go top left so i use top__left as a class , for a menu i.e. top__right etc ...

```
  .top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2%;
  &__left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2%;
    left: 1%;
  }
  &__right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2%;
    right:1%;
  }
  &__centered {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to inherit all properties of parents selectors, but for cases where it is desirable that we have the @extend directive:

**SASS**

```
.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2%;
  &__left {
    @extend .top ;
    left: 1%;
  }
  &__right {
    @extend .top;
    right:1%;
  }
  &__centered {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.top, .top__left, .top__right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2%;
}
.top__left {
  left: 1%;
}
.top__right {
  right: 1%;
}
.top__centered {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use multiple classes:

```
.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2%;
  &.left {
    left: 1%;
  }
  &.right {
    right:1%;
  }
  &.centered {
    top: initial;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
<div class="top left"></div>
<div class="top right"></div>
<div class="top centered"></div>
```